# Find the Fisher Information for geometric distribution

Tags: distributions, self-study, maximum-likelihood, fisher-information, geometric-distribution

Given $X1,\dotsc,Xn \sim \mathcal{Geo}(p)$ , and I need to find the MLE and the CI for the MLE.

I found the MLE for this distribution, using the maximum likelihood function: $L(p;X) = (1-p)^(Xi-1) * p$

I took the $log$ of $L(p;X)$ and then the derivative of it, and found that $\hat{p} =  1/\bar{X}$.

Now, what should I do in order to find the confidence interval for the MLE?

I have an idea but I'm totally not sure about it, and it is via using Fisher Information:

1. Find the score function $s(X;p)$
2. Take the derivative of it, $s'(X;p)$
3. Use this formula: $I(p) = E[-s'(X;p)]$
4. Use this formula: $se = \sqrt{1/I(p)}$

So far I found the score: $$s(X;p) = (Xp-1)/p(p-1)$$ (which I don't know if it's a good result or not).

###### My question is:

I would be glad if you could help me find the right score function if this is not a correct result, and also could use some help with how to utilize $s'(X;p)$, or in other words, how to calculate $E[-s'(X;p)]$.

##### EDIT -

So I calculated the $-s'(X;p)$ and I got $$(-Xp^2 - 2p + 1)/(p-1)^2 * p$$

Then $$I(p) = E[-s'(X;p)] = p^3 + 2p - 1 / p^2 * (p-1)^2$$

$$ \hat{se} = \sqrt{1/I(P)} = \sqrt{p^2 * (p-1)^2 / p^3 + 2p - 1} $$

And the CI is:

$$ C = (p - 2* \sqrt{p^2 * (p-1)^2 / p^3 + 2p - 1}, p + 2 * \sqrt{p^2 * (p-1)^2 / p^3 + 2p - 1}) $$

What do you guys think?

Comment: If you want to construct CIs in large samples, you can use as pivot $\sqrt{\mathcal I(\theta)}^{-1}\frac{\partial \ln L}{\partial \theta}\sim \mathcal N(0, 1).$

Comment: @User1865345 did I get the score function right?

Comment: I would suggest to correctly format the equations at the outset in the post.

Comment: @User1865345 Yes, great idea.

Comment: The easiest way to calculate the Fisher information is as the Hessian if the log normalizer.

Comment: @NeilG Still haven't got to this method unfortunately

Comment: @CORy What's  your goal with this?  Are you practicing calculating the Fisher information?  Is this an assignment?  If it's curiosity, I suggest you read up about exponential families.   They have simple formulas for the score, Fisher information, etc.

Comment: @NeilG this is an assignment yes. It's about finding confidence intervals.. and I did it, I'm just not sure about my solution that's all.